# Find root in sagemath

Tags: sage

I am very new to sagemath, so sorry for maybe too easy question. I have this equation

```
%var beta, N_0, V
show(exp(-beta*N_0)*(1/beta*N_0) + 1 - 1/(beta*N_0) - V==0)
```

I need to solve this equation for beta, but when I tried

```
solve(exp(-beta*N_0)*(1/beta*N_0) + 1 - 1/(beta*N_0) - V==0, beta)
```

it returns me.

```
[beta == 1/25*(e^(50*beta) - 2500)*e^(-50*beta)]
```

Can sagemath numerically solve this equation? Does help if I set `V = 0.5` and `N_0 = 50`?

Thx for help.

Comment: `solve` is a symbolic solver, so probably the solver cannot find a numerical solution.  Did you already set `V` and `N_0` already, as it appears from your last line?  There are also numerical root finders in Sage; perhaps `find_root` may be useful to you, though in that event you would definitely want a single-variable expression.

Comment: Ill try find_root function. I tried to set V and N_0 to some numbers, but it didnt help.

Comment: Notice that even `solve(exp(-beta*N_0)*(1/beta*N_0) + 1 - 1/(beta*N_0) - V, beta, to_poly_solve='force')` returns the empty solution set.